# how to change Add operator to custom function op2 in solve function of sympy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

**Update:**

```
>>> solve([A(x)*A(y) + A(-1), A(x) + A(-2)], x, y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in __mul__
TypeError: unbound method __multiplyFunction__() must be called with A instance
as first argument (got Symbol instance instead)

class A:
    @staticmethod
    def __additionFunction__(a1, a2):
        return a1*a2 #Put what you want instead of this
    def __multiplyFunction__(a1, a2):
        return a1*a2+a1 #Put what you want instead of this
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__.__additionFunction__(self.value, other.value)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.__class__.__multiplyFunction__(self.value, other.value)

solve([A(x)*A(y) + A(-1), A(x) + A(-2)], x, y)
```

**update2:**

```
>>> ss([x*y + -1, x-2], x, y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: solve instance has no __call__ method

 class AA:
    @staticmethod
    def __additionFunction__(a1, a2):
        return a1*a2 #Put what you want instead of this
    def __multiplyFunction__(a1, a2):
        return a1*a2+a1 #Put what you want instead of this
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__.__additionFunction__(self.value, other.value)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.__class__.__multiplyFunction__(self.value, other.value)


ss = solve(AA)
ss([x*y + -1, x-2], x, y)
```

would like to change Add operator to custom function op2 in solve function 
and then this solve([x*y - 1, x + 2], x, y) 
during solve, the parameters also change Add to custom function op2

error because i do not know how to inject op2 as ast tree to be used by ast tree

```
>>> class ChangeAddToMultiply(ast.NodeTransformer, ast2.NodeTransformer): 
...     """Wraps all integers in a call to Integer()""" 
...     def visit_BinOp(self, node): 
...         print(dir(node)) 
...         print(dir(node.left)) 
...         if isinstance(node.op, ast.Add): 
...             ast.Call(Name(id="op2", ctx=ast2.Load()), [node.left, node.right 
], []) 
...         return node 
... 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
NameError: name 'ast2' is not defined 
>>> 
>>> code = inspect.getsourcelines(solve) 
>>> tree = ast.parse(code) 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse 
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST) 
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object 
>>> tree2 = ast.parse("def op2(a,b): return a*b+a") 
>>> tree = ChangeAddToMultiply().visit(tree,tree2) 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
NameError: name 'tree' is not defined 
>>> ast.fix_missing_locations(tree) 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
NameError: name 'tree' is not defined 
>>> co = compile(tree, '<ast>', "exec") 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
NameError: name 'tree' is not defined 
>>> 
>>> exec(code) 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
TypeError: exec: arg 1 must be a string, file, or code object 
>>> exec(co)
```

---

original code

```
import ast 
from __future__ import division 
from sympy import * 
x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t') 
k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True) 
f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function) 
import inspect 
def op2(a,b): 
    return a*b+a 

class ChangeAddToMultiply(ast.NodeTransformer, ast2.NodeTransformer): 
    """Wraps all integers in a call to Integer()""" 
    def visit_BinOp(self, node): 
        print(dir(node)) 
        print(dir(node.left)) 
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.Add): 
            ast.Call(Name(id="op2", ctx=ast2.Load()), [node.left, node.right], []) 
        return node 


code = inspect.getsourcelines(solve([x*y - 1, x - 2], x, y)) 
tree = ast.parse(code) 
tree2 = ast.parse("def op2(a,b): return a*b+a") 
tree = ChangeAddToMultiply().visit(tree,tree2) 
ast.fix_missing_locations(tree) 
co = compile(tree, '<ast>', "exec") 

exec(code) 
exec(co)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `__add__` is what you're looking for.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value*other.value + 4

>>> a = A(3)
>>> b = A(4)
>>> a + b
16
```

**EDIT:**

A solution to replace the `+` operator with a function already existing:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def additionFunction(a1, a2):
        return a1*a2 #Put what you want instead of this

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__.additionFunction(self.value, other.value)
```

This one is a bit more tricky. In my opinion, that `additionFunction` is meant to belong to the `A` class, but there is no such thing as static methods in Python. So this function must be called from `self`: `self.__class__.additionFunction`.

To go further, one could imagine a solution using a meta-class `Addable`, whose constructor would take an `additionFunction` as parameter... But it might not be worth it.

Comment: i am asking to replace a add operator with custom function op2 in solve function, how to apply your solution to solve function?

Comment: @user353573 Edited and added an example. Still, the easiest way would have been writing `op2(self, other)` instead of `self.value*other.value + 4`, which obviously was an example...

Comment: how do it use with sympy solve function? do you mean that sympy solve function can use extension method to override addition in it?

Comment: @user353573 Well, you should try it to be sure, but when you override `__add__` in a class, it redefines the addition for the instances of that class, so anytime Python comes across `a+b`, it will know that it means `__add__(a, b)`. Actually, when Python sees `a+b`, it calls the `__add__` method from the class of `a` and `b`, and raises an error if that method cannot be found.

Comment: class AA:
    @staticmethod
    def __additionFunction__(a1, a2):
        return a1*a2 #Put what you want instead of this
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__.__additionFunction__(self.value, other.value)
    

ss = solve(AA)

ss([x*y - 1, x - 2], x, y)

AttributeError: solve instance has no __call__ method

Comment: i updated two trial which both has errors, how to use with solve function?

Comment: @user353573 I don't understand well what you're trying to do. Still, here is my thought: `solve` seems most likely to be a class, of which you create an instance by writing `ss = solve(AA)`. But you use `ss` as a function, with the `ss(...)` syntax. This is possible only by implementing the `__call__` method, which will make your class's instances callable. Still, we are going really far from your original question. Besides, as a side-note, **do not use the `__  __` markers for your own functions**. Though it's legal, this naming is reserved to Python's magic attributes.